# Wordpress + Nginx: 'Site within Site'

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Say I have wordpress installed and served at `example.com` using `nginx`.

I would like `example.com/microsite` to be served by a separate wordpress installation in another root directory.

I've included my nginx configuration which is not working. the calls to `/microsite` are passed to the main site's `index.php` and I get a 404.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/Example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";

    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/www.example.com;
    index index.php;

    access_log off;
    client_max_body_size 15M;
    gzip on;

    ########## BEGIN MICRO-SITES

        # Mini Site Conference
        location /minisite/ {
            root /var/www/minisite;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        #END Mini Site Conference

    ######### END MICRO-SITES

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if there's  a better approach which is a different sever block and some other form of invisible rewrite.

Comment: This doesnt look like a stackoverflow question, more like a server fault. Can you on the debugs for ngnix and look into the HTTP request URI to see the request website

Answer (score 0):

Was easier to just move the subdirectory inside the main wordpress file and use the following:

```
# Micro site
location /microsite/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /microsite/index.php?$args;
}
```